# connected but not path-connected sets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Let $S\in[0,1]^2$ be defined as follows:
$$(x,y)\in S \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}y\in[0, \frac{1}{q}], &x=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q} \text{ with } q \text{ even}\\
y\in[1-\frac{1}{q}, 1], &x=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q} \text{ with } q \text{ odd}\\
y\in[0,1], &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
, where for every $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, the fractional representation $\frac{p}{q}$ is lowest in terms of $q>0$. Prove that $A$ is connected, but not pathwise connected.

I found that proving the connectedness of $S$ directly from definition is hard. So I'm trying to prove it using the property of connectedness that if $A\subset S\subset \bar{A}$, where $A$ is connected, then $S$ is connected. However, I'm having trouble finding this connected subset $A$. Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess it would be difficult to find such a $A$ : indeed, you can see that $\overline{S}=[0,1]^2$, so if you had such an $A$, then $\overline{A} = [0,1]^2$ also. So basically finding a $A$ is equivalent to find a connected subset of $S$ which is dense in $[0,1]^2$. This does not seem easier than proving directly that $S$ is connected.

Comment: I suggest using the function criterion of connectedness, a topological space $X$ is connected if and only if every continuous $f \colon X \to \{0,1\}$ (the latter with the discrete topology) is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we had two non-empty clopen sets $U, V$ partitioning $S$. Each set of the form $\{x\} \times [0, 1] \subseteq S$, where $x \in [0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}$, must be entirely contained in $U$ or entirely contained in $V$, since each such subset is connected.

Let $A = \{x \in [0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q} : \{x\} \times [0, 1] \subseteq U\}$ and similarly define $B$ in relation to $V$. I claim that $A$ and $B$ are clopen in $[0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}$. To see $A$ is open, suppose $x \in A$. Then $(x, 0) \in U$, which is open, hence a ball $B_S((x, y); r)$ exists in $U$. It's straight forward to verify that $B_A(x; r) \subseteq A$. Similarly, $B$ is open, and given both partition $[0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}$, $A$ and $B$ are both clopen.

Due to the density of the irrationals, and the fact that $U, V$ are open and non-empty, we can also verify that $A$ and $B$ are both non-empty.

Consider now the closures of $A$ and $B$ in $[0, 1]$. The density of the irrationals imply that the closures of these sets cover $[0, 1]$. By the connectedness of $[0, 1]$, there must exist some point in their intersection. That is, there exists some $x$ that is simultaneously the limit (in $[0, 1]$) of a sequence $a_n \in A$ and a sequence $b_n \in B$. As both $A$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint, we must have $x \in \Bbb{Q}$.

Now, if $x$ has even lowest denominator, then consider the sequences $(a_n, 0)$ and $(b_n, 0)$. If $x$ has odd lowest denominator, then consider the sequences $(a_n, 1)$ and $(b_n, 1)$. In either case, each sequence respectively belongs to $A$ and $B$, converging to a point in $S$. As $U$ and $V$ are closed, this would produce a point in $U \cap V$, contradicting $U$ and $V$ being disjoint, and proving connectedness.

Comment: "As both $A$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint, we must have $x\in\Bbb Q$." Closed where? In $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$? Why does it entail $x\in\Bbb Q$?

Comment: If $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$, then a sequence in $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ that converges to $x$ from closed sets $A$ and $B$ must lie in both $A$ and $B$, which would contradict the disjointness of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: But $A$ and $B$ are closed in $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$. How do you know they are closed in $[0,1]$ too?

Comment: They're not; they're closed in $[0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}$. So sequences from these sets (which lie in $[0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}$) that converge in $[0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}$, must converge to a point in these closed sets. That's what it means for these sets to be closed in $[0, 1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: $x$ is a point in the closures of $A$ and $B$ in $[0,1]$, so there are two sequences $a_n\in A$ and $b_n\in B$ that are convergent on $[0,1]$ with limit $x$, but if $x\in [0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ then the sequences are also convergent on $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ and thus $x$ would have to be in both $A$ and $B$. Is that correct (specially the thing about convergence on $[0,1]$ and on $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$)?

Comment: That's right, yes.